# an algorithm for uniquely random patterns of colors for Christmas lights written in AppleScript

Tags: algorithm, applescript

This post is ultimately about creating files of random patterns for smart Christmas lights.

I have 7 colors (Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Purple, White, Dark) that I have chosen that I want to semi-randomize.

I have 4 "frames" that is a 5 wide x 4 tall grid that I want to fill with "random" colors, with no color being side my side, or directly up and down from one another and no color repeating between frames in each grid location.

Here are examples of what the totally random frames might look like. Completely random is easy, it is the "no duplicates" random that I am looking for. Again, these frames are NOT what I am ultimately looking for, but they are close. Also the following is purely for visual reference, in AppleScript (or probably any other programming language), the following would be a list of lists.

```
P G O R D     D O G D O    P W D O G    W O G B W
W B P D O     P G R G B    R G B O P    D R B P G
R G B D O     R O G O W    P O W D R    O G R W D    
B G W D B     D R G P R    R W D O B    B O G D W
```

So here is some code that gets me to the first column of the first frame:

```
set colorList to {"R", "G", "B", "D", "O", "W", "P"}
set newColumn to {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
set previousColor to {}
set previousColumn to {}


repeat with i from 1 to 4 -- for the 4 frames that I need
    repeat with j from 1 to 5 -- for the 5 columns that each frame needs
        repeat with k from 1 to 4 -- for the 4 values I need in each column
            set isRandom to false
            set theColor to some item of colorList
            if i is not greater than 1 then -- if i is 1 then it is the first frame of the series
                if j is not greater than 1 then -- if J is 1 then it is the first column
                    if k is not greater than 1 then -- if K is 1 then its the first value of the column
                        set end of (item j of newColumn) to theColor
                        
                    else
                        if theColor is not previousColor then -- if k is greater than 1 then ¬
                            --check the color against the previous color, to make sure they are not the same
                            set end of (item j of newColumn) to theColor
                            set previousColor to theColor
                        else
                            repeat until isRandom is true
                                set theColor to some item of colorList
                                if theColor is not previousColor then
                                    set end of (item j of newColumn) to theColor
                                    set isRandom to true
                                end if
                            end repeat
                        end if
                    end if
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end repeat
```

I have tried to go further than, but every time I do, it becomes an incoherent mess of if-then-else statements that I get lost in.

So the script needs to do 3 things before it adds a color to the column:

1. Make sure that the previous color of the column is not the same
2. Make sure (if the column we are dealing with is not column 1) that the color is not the same as the previous columns item,
3. Make sure (if the frame we are dealing with is beyond the first frame) that the color is not the same as it was in the same position as the frame before.

So the question that I am asking is, is their a handler or algorithm here that I am missing (I am no CS Major) that would make this task more straightforward?

That is all you probably NEED to know about my issue, but for reference sake, I am trying to create the patterns for Christmas lights. The `colorList` in my script actually looks like this:

```
set colorList to {{255, 0, 0}, {0, 255, 0}, {0, 0, 255}, {255, 255, 255}, {255, 128, 0}, {255, 255, 0},{0, 0, 0}}
```

So in the end I need a text file that is formatted exactly like this:

```
 255, 0, 0
 0, 0, 255
 0, 0, 0
 255, 255, 0
```

(there is a space character in front of each line).

I take the text file, convert it over to binary, and then use some Python to send the file to the REST API that the lights are using.
The lights are from a company called Twinkly.
I am just trying to make the process of creating some scenes easier for me (and learn something in the process, hopefully).

Comment: CompSci 127: don't replicate; iterate! You can clean up a lot of the messy if/then structures by calling recursive handlers. This would be a *lot* less of a headache in AppleScriptObjC, though; don't know if you're open to that.

Comment: @TedWrigley I am open to anything that does not put me in the “hell of if-then-else”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I went ahead and did this without objC. The approach I used was to first build an empty array of an appropriate size and shape, and then run through the array adding colors, blocking the colors from being added to farther-on adjacent cells. It has some tricky aspects — recursions to drill down through the nested lists, using references for speed optimization and list processing, mocking up a version of an indexPath to locate list elements — but you ought to get the idea of it fairly quickly.

I've left the finalization of the script to you; this produces a list of text elements in the property `fullList` that you can convert into the form you need. If you have any questions, ask in the comments.

```
property colorList : {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Purple", "White", "Dark"}
property fullList : missing value

property columns : 5
property rows : 4
property blocks : 4

my buildEmptyNestedList()
my setColorsRecursivelyInNestedList:(a reference to fullList) withIndexList:{}
return get fullList

on buildEmptyNestedList()
    set fullList to {}
    set fullListRef to a reference to fullList
    repeat blocks times
        set blocksList to {}
        repeat rows times
            set rowsList to {}
            repeat columns times
                set end of rowsList to {}
            end repeat
            copy rowsList to end of blocksList
        end repeat
        copy blocksList to end of fullListRef
    end repeat
end buildEmptyNestedList

on setColorsRecursivelyInNestedList:nestedListElement withIndexList:idxList
    local idx
    
    if lists of nestedListElement is equal to {} then -- bottom level: empty list or list of strings
        set localColors to my filterColorsByList:nestedListElement
        set chosenColor to some item of localColors
        set excludePathsList to my processPathList:idxList
        repeat with aPathList in excludePathsList
            set target to (my getSublistByIndexes:aPathList)
            copy chosenColor to end of target
        end repeat
        set contents of nestedListElement to chosenColor
    else
        set idx to 1
        repeat with aSublist in nestedListElement
            copy idxList to nextIdxList
            set nextIdxList to nextIdxList & idx
            (my setColorsRecursivelyInNestedList:(a reference to (item idx of nestedListElement)) withIndexList:nextIdxList)
            set idx to idx + 1
        end repeat
    end if
end setColorsRecursivelyInNestedList:withIndexList:

on getSublistByIndexes:idxList
    set foundList to item (item 1 of idxList) of fullList
    repeat with idx in (rest of idxList)
        set foundList to item idx of foundList
    end repeat
    return foundList
end getSublistByIndexes:

on getElementFromList:aNestedList byIndexes:idxArray
    set currIdx to item 1 of idxArray
    if (count of idxArray) = 1 then
        return item currIdx of aNestedList
    else
        return my getElementFromList:(item currIdx of aNestedList) byIndexes:(rest of idxArray)
    end if
end getElementFromList:byIndexes:

on processPathList:aPathList
    set pathCheckList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of aPathList
        copy aPathList to tempList
        set item i of tempList to (item i of tempList) + 1
        if item i of tempList ≤ item i of {blocks, rows, columns} then
            copy tempList to end of pathCheckList
        end if
    end repeat
    return pathCheckList
end processPathList:

on filterColorsByList:aList
    set filteredList to {}
    set colorListRef to a reference to colorList
    repeat with aColor in colorListRef
        if aColor is not in aList then
            copy aColor as text to end of filteredList
        end if
    end repeat
    return filteredList
end filterColorsByList:
```

Comment: Thank You so much! It works perfectly, and as I examine it more hopefully teach me a thing or two about this CS stuff. I do have one question about the code, how difficult would in be for the ColorList variable to be a list of lists, instead of a list of strings? I tried it out with a list of lists, but your script striped all the list parts away. The final "code" that I need are colors in their RGB value format, so Red is { 255, 0, 0}. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisNorman: Not *too* difficult, I imagine.  The only place it would matter is the line `if lists of nestedListElement is equal to {} then`. This line filters the list for 'list' elements, on the assumption that the deepest level will not have any sublists (just text, or nothing).Making your color elements an RGB would throw that line off making it go down an extra level), but you could certainly adapt the code.

Comment: @ChrisNorman: an easier solution, though, might be to shift things and do a translation at the end. Specifically, change `colorList` from `{"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Purple", "White", "Dark"}` to a list of integers: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`; add  a new property `RGBList` with a list of lists: `{{255, 0, 0}, {0, 255, 0}, {0, 0, 255},...}`. Then later, when you are writing out to disk, substitute with `item idx of RGBList`, where `idx` is the value you get from `fullList`.

Comment: I could just keep the color names, use them as the index and then change the values at the end, which is what I had been thinking about doing. Thanks Again.